# Lift: how make these relations polymorphic?

Tags: scala, lift

I got a Entry
it should be related to one of three "Lists" call them ListA ListB ListC
i couldnt figure out how to do this with LongMappedMapper.
So how could i do this?

I wanted to let the List have multiple entries without having to specify a listX relation for each kind of list.
So **not**:

```
class Entry ...{
    object listA extends LongMappedMapper(this,ListA)
    object listB extends LongMappedMapper(this,ListB)
    ...
}
```

I want something like:

```
class Entry ...{
    object list extends PolyLongMappedMapper(this,ListA,ListB,ListC)
    //PolyLongMappedMapper i the example mapper what i want
    ...
}
```

or:

```
class Entry ...{
    object list extends PolyLongMappedMapper(this,BaseListTrait)
    //where BaseListTrait is a Trait shared by all List classes
    //PolyLongMappedMapper i the example mapper what i want
    ...
}
```

Is somewere something in the Lift framework what does what i want? what is comparable to the PolyLongMappedMapper?
Or is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: If your question requires clarification, edit the question to provide the additional detail. Using 'answer' to try and have a conversation doesn't work on SO, as the order is based on votes, not time of entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not perfect but i created a workaround.
I couldnt find a  way to do the polymorphism in both directions in a nice way.

So lets start with the role. the Role holds internally the Rights of a RolePlayer ie. a User or a process or whatever.
The Roleplayer plays a Role in a Appliable. The appliable is a File or a folder or something else in the system. 
the applialbe has many roles. a roleplayer has many roles. for not having to define for each appliable the relation and just having to extend with the trait Appliable i created the Workarout wit appliableId and appliableClass in the Role class.

```
class Role extends BaseModel[Role] {
  def getSingleton = Role

  object appliableId extends MappedLong(this)

  object appliableClass extends MappedString(this, 300)

  def setAppliable (appliable: Appliable[_]) = {
    rolePlayerId(appliable.id.is)
    rolePlayerClass(validClassName(appliable))
  }

  def validClassName(appliable: Appliable[_]) = {
    appliable.getClass.getName
  }
  def appliable={
    Class.forName(appliableClass).asInstanceOf[Appliable[_]].findById(appliableId.is)
  }
   object rolePlayerId extends MappedLong(this)

  object rolePlayerClass extends MappedString(this, 300)

  def setRolePlayer (appliable: Appliable[_]) = {
    rolePlayerId(appliable.id.is)
    rolePlayerClass(validClassName(appliable))
  }


  def rolePlayer={
    Class.forName(rolePlayerClass).asInstanceOf[RolePlayer[_]].findById(rolePlayerId.is)
  }
}

object Role extends Role with BaseMetaModel[Role] {

}
```

This is the Appliable ie. a Folder or a Blog entry.

```
trait Appliable[T <: BaseModel[T]] {
  this: T =>

  def findById(i: Long): Box[T]

  def id: MappedLong[T]

  def getRoles = {
    Role.findAll(By(Role.appliableId, id.is), By(Role.appliableClass, Role.validClassName(Appliable.this)))
  }

  def addRole(role: Role) = {
    role.setAppliable(Appliable.this)
  }
}

class App1 extends BaseModel[App1] with Appliable[App1] {
  def getSingleton = App1
}

object App1 extends App1 with BaseMetaModel[App1]

class App2 extends BaseModel[App2] with Appliable[App2] {
  def getSingleton = App2
}

object App2 extends App2 with BaseMetaModel[App2]
```

And here a short test with FunSuite:

```
test("appliables should have roles") {
    val a = App1.create
    val b = App2.create
    List(a, b).map(_.save)
    val ra1 = Role.create.setAppliable(a)
    val ra2 = Role.create.setAppliable(a)
    val rb1 = Role.create.setAppliable(b)
    val rb2 = Role.create.setAppliable(b)

    List(ra1, ra2, rb1, rb2).map(_.save)
    val ar = App1.find(By(a.id, a.id.is)).get.getRoles.toList
    assert(ar(0) == ra1, ar(0) + " was not " + ra1)
    assert(ar(1) == ra2, ar(1) + " was not " + ra2)
    val br = b.getRoles.toList
    assert(br(0) == rb1, br(0) + "  was not " + rb1)
    assert(br(1) == rb2, br(1) + " was not " + rb2)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in such a way:

```
class A extends LongKeyedMapper[A] with IdPK {
    object entry extends LongMappedMapper(this, Entry)
    ...

class B extends LongKeyedMapper[B] with IdPK {
    object entry extends LongMappedMapper(this, Entry)
    ...

class C extends LongKeyedMapper[C] with IdPK {
    object entry extends LongMappedMapper(this, Entry)
    ...

class Entry extends LongKeyedMapper[Entry] with IdPK {
    def aList = A.findAll(By(A.entry, this))
    def bList = B.findAll(By(B.entry, this))
    def cList = C.findAll(By(C.entry, this))
    ...
```

And your lista are:

```
e.aList, e.bList, e.cList
```

when:

```
val e: Entry
```

Etam.

Comment: Okay that would be the direct way.